# ansible install node.js version 6

Tags: node.js, ansible

For installing the node 6.x version these are the commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

now how exactly do I do that in ansible?
any ideas here?

this is what I had till now, but it installs the old version

```
---
- name: Ensure Ubuntu Distro is Supported
  get_url:
    url='https://deb.nodesource.com/node/dists/"{{ ansible_distribution_release }}"/Release'
    dest=/dev/null
  register: distrosupported


- name: Remove Old Chris Lea PPA
  apt_repository:
    repo='ppa:chris-lea/node.js'
    state=absent
  when: distrosupported|success
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Remove Old Chris Lea Sources
  sudo: yes
  file:
    path='/etc/apt/sources.list.d/chris-lea-node_js-"{{ ansible_distribution_release }}".list'
    state=absent
  when: distrosupported|success
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Add Nodesource Keys
  sudo: yes
  apt_key:
    url=https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key
    state=present

- name: Add Nodesource Apt Sources List Deb
  sudo: yes
  apt_repository:
    repo='deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node "{{ ansible_distribution_release }}" main'
    state=present
  when: distrosupported|success

- name: Add Nodesource Apt Sources List Deb Src
  sudo: yes
  apt_repository:
    repo='deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node "{{ ansible_distribution_release }}" main'
    state=present
  when: distrosupported|success

- name: Install NodeJS
  sudo: yes
  apt: pkg=nodejs state=latest update_cache=true
  when: distrosupported|success





- debug: msg="{{npm_pkgs}}"


- name: install global npm packages
  sudo: yes
  npm: name={{item}} global=yes state=latest
  with_items: "{{npm_pkgs}}"
```

Comment: added my old and current code

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with what you've tried?

Comment: mine installs node version 0.1, I want version 6. I node docs you do it like this: curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Comment: That setup file adds this repo: `deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x ${DISTRO} main` while your playbook is adding `deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node "{{ ansible_distribution_release }}`. Does it work if you just add the `_6.x` to the repo name?

Answer (score 8):

I was using this playbook for installing node 6.1.0 via nvm(node version manager):

Note: You may need to change the hosts and connection in the play.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local 
  vars:
    node_version: 6.1.0
  tasks:
    - name: Download the nvm(node version manager) install script
      get_url: url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh dest=/tmp/install.sh

    - name: Install dependencies 
      apt: pkg={{ item }} update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600
      with_items:
        - git
        - curl
        - build-essential
        - libssl-dev
      become: yes
      become_user: root

    - name: Execute the nvm install script
      shell: bash install.sh chdir=/tmp executable=/bin/bash

    - name: Register the NVM_DIR
      shell: echo $NVM_DIR
      register: nvm_dir 

    - name: Install the specified node version using the nvm command and set it as default
      shell: . {{ nvm_dir.stdout }}/nvm.sh && nvm install {{ node_version }} && nvm run {{node_version}} --version && nvm alias default {{node_version}}
             creates=~/.nvm/versions/node/v{{ node_version }}
```

For more information on nvm, see: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 4):

Based on the code in the original question, and the [helpful comment from @ydaetskcoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37137513/ansible-install-node-js-version-6/46277652#comment61820408_37137513), I was able to install NodeJS 6.x with the following on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
- name: Add Nodesource Keys
  become: yes
  apt_key:
    url: https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key
    state: present

# Note: "xenial" is ubuntu-speak for 16.04
- name: Add Nodesource Apt Sources
  become: yes
  apt_repository:
    repo: '{{ item }}'
    state: present
  with_items:
    - 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial main'
    - 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial main'

- name: Install NodeJS and NPM
  become: yes
  apt:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
  with_items:
    - nodejs
    - nodejs-legacy
    - npm
```

---

I've refactored a little for brevity, but **the most important thing is the addition of `_6.x` to the repository URLs**.

This worked for me using Ansible 2.3.2.0